# Disabled Local Policies:Audit Policy, but Event Viewer is still displaying Security Logs

Tags: windows-server-2012, event-viewer, security-policy

I disabled all types of auditing for both successes and failures in:

Local Security Policy > Local Policies > Audit Policy

but when I go to Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Security, logs are still being captured.

The "Advanced security audit policies" are also not configured. I checked that it is not registered to any Domain Controller/GPO.

[image: Event viewer]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a work machine under the control of an IT Department? They could mandate settings you cannot override.

Comment: This is a brand new EC2 instance in the cloud -- maybe taking on settings of its AMI? In any case, I am an Administrator user.I should be able to do everything right?